# Could a space elevator really be built from the top down?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, string

I think most of us have this picture of a space elevator being built by lowering a cable from a platform in orbit until it reaches the ground. Leaving aside the technological hurdle of building a cable strong enough— how would this be possible given basic laws of orbital motion?

How is it possible to keep the cable pointed down towards earth when the end of the cable is at a lower altitude with a corresponding higher orbital velocity? It would seem that the end of the cable would start to move towards prograde the moment it begins to lower.

Does the end of the cable need a continuous source of thrust in the retrograde direction while it's being lowered?

Comment: Yes I think it does.

Comment: And the next question is 'could a space elevator really be build from the bottom up?'...

Comment: Related:  [Is it better to build a space elevator from GEO down to the surface of the Earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71968/is-it-better-to-build-a-space-elevator-from-geo-down-to-the-surface-of-the-earth)

Answer (score 0):

If an object is in a circular orbit and *gravity is the only force acting on it*, then a lower elevations does indeed imply a faster orbit.  If $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the orbit (radians/second around the circle), then the relationship between $r$ and $\omega$ can be expressed in the Physics-101-exercise way by equating centripetal force with gravitational force:
$$
F_R = F_G \quad \Rightarrow \quad m r \omega^2 = G \frac{m M_E}{r^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \omega = \sqrt{ \frac{G M_E}{r^3}}.
$$

But the lower end of a descending space elevator doesn't only have gravity pulling it downwards;  it also has an upward tension $T$ from the cable above it.  We therefore have
$$
m r \omega^2 = G \frac{m M_E}{r^2} - T \quad \Rightarrow \quad T = G \frac{m M_E}{r^2} - m r \omega^2.
$$
Thus, for a given radius $r$, we can get the object to orbit at any angular velocity $\omega$ by picking the tension correctly.

Comment: Makes sense. But in order to have tension in the first place, doesn't one end of the cable need to have a continual thrust applied to it? In other words— we can't get around the fact that some part of the system will need to have thrust until it reaches the ground (or atmospheric drag is high enough)?

Comment: @JimHeising: I believe this is why you have to simultaneously build a tether *out* from geosynchronous orbit.  If you play the inward and outward tethers out at the appropriate speed, the inward force needed to keep the outer tether moving fast enough is exactly balanced by the outward force needed to keep the inner tether from moving too fast.  (I think.)

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense now. Reminds me of one of those retractable charger/audio cables :D

Comment: Actually, now that I think about this more— I'm not sure this will work. Think of it like a geostationary satellite. A geostationary satellite must spin 360 degrees over a 24 hour period in order to stay pointed at earth. So if you imagine this elevator cable system is just like a geostationary satellite— its cables are just like REALLY long antennas— it too has to rotate once every 24 hours to keep pointed in the right direction. You could never get a system that large to rotate that quickly without immense amounts of force. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can spin a geostationary satellite at the beginning and it will keep going for the most part with minimal ongoing correction. But this cable system will act like a figure skater spreading his/her arms. There's no way to keep it spinning without continual increasing force.

Comment: @JimHeising The major factor left out of Michael's answer is the tidal effect. Once you start building out the two ends, the tidal forces experienced by the ends help to stabilize the orientation. You'll want a little bit of trim capability to damp any oscillations, but the system basically takes care of itself.

Comment: Interesting. Are your referring to Gravity Gradient Stabilization? Has this ever been proven to work? For example: https://books.google.com/books?id=xDzEkslhpUwC&pg=PA345#v=onepage&q&f=false says "To summarize: for most applications, gravity gradient stabilization is inadequate." It seems like it only works (and not very well) with active systems and at very short distances. Is this a case of "we just haven't learned how to make it work yet" or does it slip into the realm of chaos and n-body theory at longer lengths? Maybe the question should be, can a reliable GGS system actually be built?